# Sql add condition IF

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause

I have sql like :

```
SELECT * FROM leads_notes WHERE content <> '' AND lead_id <> ''
```

I need add rule **if type <> close_task then write user_change_task_status IS NULL**

My result sql is:

```
SELECT * FROM leads_notes WHERE content <> '' AND lead_id <> ''  IF(task_type <> 'close_task', 'AND user_change_task_status IS NULL',)
```

But i get many errors. 
Cant understand how can i solve this. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `if`.  Boolean logic is sufficient:

```
WHERE content <> '' AND
      lead_id <> '' AND
      ( type = 'close_task' or user_change_task is null)
```

Or:

```
WHERE content <> '' AND
      lead_id <> '' AND
      NOT ( type = 'close_task' and user_change_task is not null )
```